# Robolectric ShadowGeocoder class file not found

Tags: android, robolectric

I want to create a ShadowGeocoder with Robolectric:

```
    Field field = FetchAddressIntentService.class.getDeclaredField("geocoder");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Geocoder geocoderMemberVariable = (Geocoder) field.get(fetchAddressIntentService);
    ShadowGeocoder shadowGeocoder = Shadows.shadowOf(geocoderMemberVariable);
    shadowGeocoder.setSimulatedResponse(ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP, COUNTRY_CODE);
```

But at Shadows.shadowOf I am getting the error:

```
Error:(63, 48) error: cannot access OverlayItem
class file for com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem not found
```

In my gradle I am using:

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-maps:3.0'
```

How to solve this?